# What is the simplest way to add XML documentation to Swagger?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, .net-8.0, xml-documentation

This Q&A question is meant as a helpful references for myself and hopefully for the community. I use Swagger for all my web APIs, and like it to include my source code documentation, as Swagger is to a largely about documentation.

I've long used the following from some example online, but `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions` is now deprecated, `GetTypeInfo` requires `using System.Reflection;`, and the code is overall complex for just getting the path to an XML file:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using System.Reflection;
// ...
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
    var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
    var fileName = typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name + ".xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
    options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});
```

A small readability improvement came later, but requires `Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions`, which was [removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/platformabstractions-package-removed).

```
    ...
    var basePath = ApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
    ...
```

I briefly used this slightly shorter code, but it still requires an explicit reference to `System.Reflection`:

```
using System.Reflection;
// ...
var xmlFileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".xml";
Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFileName); // A bit too long to combine into 1 line
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => { options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocsPath); });
```

While modern .NET has made most programming tasks simpler in my experience than other languages I have used (PHP, Python, Java and C++), this one seems a bit complicated for how common I believe it is.

Is there a simpler way to add XML documentation to Swagger, preferably without hard-coding the program name or use of any reflection?

---

*For future readers: XML files are not generated by default. Search online for how to enable it in your project or with your IDE.
For Jetbrains Rider: Open project properties and check the "Generate" box for under Debug and/or Release.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've settled on the following most recently. `Assembly.GetName()` looks very reflectiony despite the code no longer requiring an explicit reference to `System.Reflection` but that's fine as this is overall reasonably simple and short, and works for me:

```
var xmlDocsPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name + ".xml");
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => { options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocsPath); });
```

Replace `Program` with your startup class, if named differently.

The program name is gathered because the default XML file name in most IDEs is `{ProgramName}.xml`, but you can just as easily make it part of your setup process to name the file explicitly, and use that name in place of the `Assembly.GetName...`.

Comment: JFYI While you don't need explicitly specify `using`, `Assembly` itself is [defined in `System.Reflection` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly?view=net-8.0) so you still are using reflection.